# My Iron Golem got himself stuck inside of a mine cart

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

An Iron Golem of mine walked and loaded himself into a mine cart. I'm trying to get him out but I can't destroy the mine cart itself because the Iron Golem hit box stops me from hitting it. Any ideas to get him out?

Comment: Did you try digging directly underneath the minecart and breaking it from below?

Answer (score 2):

Can you place rails under it or push the golem-cart onto nearby rails? Build a short little track that ends in an [**Activator Rail**](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Activator_Rail) which will eject mobs from the minecart as it drives over (including your iron golem)

If not, you can still build your track underneath, and then dig out the block the minecart is on to make it fall onto the Activator Rail.